# SSE instruction sanity check

Tags: c++, sse

The code below has me slightly perplexed:

```
function(__m128 foo)
{
  __m128 bar = _mm_shuffle_ps(foo, foo, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,2,2,2))
}
```

Is it just taking the 2nd word of foo and pasting it 4 times into bar or does it do something else as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if `_mm_shuffle` exists. It should rather be `_mm_shuffle_ps`, given the `__m128` arguments.

In this case it does exactly what you think. It copies the 3rd (not the 2nd, counting starts at 0, from the right, so it's indeed the 2nd from the left) 32-bit word of `foo` into all 4 32-bit words of `bar`. What else should it do?

Comment: Yes, I omited the ps - my bad.  The function in which I this is embedded is doing all sorts of redundant bit manipulation via _mm_and_ps instructions after the swizzle/shuffle and I thought that perhaps there was an endian swap or something I wasn't aware of.  Thanks for the sanity check and quick answer